# SQL Query Single Value from Table in a Date Range

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I need to make a query to a table that contains this columns:

```
 name | value | date         
--------+-------+--------+---------
 Jonh |  0.15 | 2021-12-23 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.14 | 2021-12-22 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.19 | 2021-12-21 00:00:00
 Jonh |  0.13 | 2021-12-15 00:00:00
 Bob  |  0.12 | 2021-12-15 00:00:00
```

I need to select, for a given name, all the values for the last 7 days. I could just do:

```
SELECT value FROM mytable WHERE name='Jonh' AND (date BETWEEN '2021-12-16 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-23 00:00:00')
```

But this will only fetch the values in DB, I need to get a list of 7 items, with a default value of `0` if there is no `value` stored in DB for that day, I'm about to create a loop in backend that iterates over each date and returns the value on DB or a default value `0`, but I was wondering if I can do this with SQL, any suggestions?

The desired output would be, for the name 'Jonh' and making the query today:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0.19, 0.14, 0.15]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer join against a list of dates:

```
select g.dt::date, coalesce(m.value, 0) as value
from generate_series(date '2021-12-16', date '2021-12-23', interval '1 day') as g(dt)
  left join mytable  m
         on m.name = 'Jonh'
        and m.date::date = g.dt::date
```

Comment: Hey, can you check my answer?   Seems based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599047/how-does-now-get-evaluated-when-passed-into-a-function-as-a-parameter my answer now() function will evaluated dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  IF(value is not null, value, 0)
FROM mytable
WHERE name='Jonh'
and (date BETWEEN '2021-12-16 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-23 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 1):

trying to make it more complicated.

```
begin;
create temp table mytable(name text, value numeric, datecol date);
insert into mytable values
('Jonh' ,  0.15 , '2021-12-23'),
('Jonh' ,  0.14 , '2021-12-22'),
('Jonh' ,  0.19 , '2021-12-21'),
('Jonh' ,  0.13 , '2021-12-15'),
('Bob'  ,  0.12 , '2021-12-15');
alter table mytable add column last7days daterange;
update mytable set last7days = daterange(now()::date - 7 , now()::date);
commit;
```

Then

```
select value from mytable where name = 'Jonh' and  datecol <@ last7days
union all
select 0 
from mytable where name = 'Jonh' and datecol <@ last7days is false;
```

I believe it will now() will evaluated dynamically, even I cannot found it in the menu.